# Could not connect to a specific host

Tags: php, network-programming

I am trying to get contents of http://betsbc.com.
But nothing could do this: cURL, wget, `file_get_contents`, Ruby's `file.open`, python's `urllib2.urlopen`. Nothing.
But i can open it from the browser successfully.
I ve tried in Cloud9 and my hosting.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: curl returns a web page (or at least, its basic structure). The rest is probably generated with javascript, which is why you don't see it.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia it couldn't even connect to the host

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko Ruby has methods for opening url too
`require 'open-uri'`
`file = open('http://wap.betsbc.com')`
`contents = file.read'`

Comment: Not for me. curl http://betsbc.com returns an html page content (which is almost empty, but still has all the <html><head><title> etc. tags)

Comment: Are you sure you are not at school or similar and therefore the site is blocked?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I tried from Cloud9 (cloud IDE) and my own hosting on Hostinger

Comment: idk what to say. Here is the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/8JYpe9B1

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia actually, thanks. Please post an answer to mark it as completed if you want

Comment: Done. Please close this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curl seems to work for me.

It returns a html page structure with almost no content, so I'd guess it's all generated in javascript.

You may have some connectivity limitations from where you are, preventing to access the website.

Here you can see the content returned: pastebin.com/8JYpe9B1

```
$ curl http://betsbc.com
<html><head><title>BetCity - ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="betcity,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,live ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,live ▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒,▒▒▒▒▒▒,on-line,sports,soccer,hockey,basketball,tennis">
<meta name="page-topic" content="sports"><meta name="description" content="Betcity - ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒. ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒.">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-120364-2");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
        </head>
<frameset rows="111,*,38" border="0">
<frame name="btop" src="top.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize>
<frame name="center" src="center.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize>
<frame name="bottom" src="bottom.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize>
</frameset></html>
```